# Spring @Schleduled annotation does not work

Tags: spring, asynchronous, task, scheduling

I want a spring scheduled task, that runs every 10 seconds, however for some reason the task runs only once and is never repeated again.

Please do not suggest me to use other types of tasks, because I need specifically to use spring tasks.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000, initialDelay = 1000)
public void myTask() {
...
}
```

In my main config class I have `@EnableScheduling` added as well.

Comment: If you could post a sample that reproduces this issue on github there would be an option to investigate. In meantime, perhaps you can learn more about scheduling at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92-qLIxv0JA and figure out your issue.

Comment: once the task started that takes more than 10 seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduling is a process of executing the tasks for a specific time period, but you looking to make it asynchrounslly so there will be a couple of changes

create a config class that will manage the `Async` operations so you make use of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class TaskConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar)
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("your-scheduler-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

then you can run jobs asynchrounslly as the below :

```
@Component
public class HelloSender {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void myTask() {

        System.out.println("im running asynchronous with Worker : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

for further information about `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` please have look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html